# jquery datepicker add extra text

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How do I add extra line text within the calendar control of the datepicker plugin.

**Datepicker opens on the** 
focus of the date field

click of the date field

click calendar image

I need to add a p tag just below the calendar...is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is all of that text between the first and last line of your question supposed to mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append the text to the `#ui-datepicker-div` *after* the calendar has been rendered. One caveat is that the datepicker tries to find the date being entered in real time, which refreshes the `#ui-datepicker-div`. The means you need to observe both `click` and `keyup` events, and only insert the message if it is not there already.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().bind('click keyup', function() {
    if ($('#ui-datepicker-div :last-child').is('table'))
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').append('<p>hello world</p>');
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/ctqUa/1/.

Comment: Thanks for that...I did the same on focus and works fine. Though I am facing an issue where if the user starts typing in the field the text gets removed...the same happens in example you gave. Any clue?

Comment: what's your code like? i am not sure what you meant by "the user starts typing in the field the text gets removed".

Comment: in the example you gave http://jsfiddle.net/william/ctqUa/ start typing in the date 27/10/2011 in the field, you will see that the text added disappears when you start typing the year.

Comment: Heres my code:

$(".datepicker").focus(function () {  
 $(".dpTip").remove();
 $('<p class="dpTip">some text here</p>).appendTo('#ui-datepicker-div');
});

Comment: I didn't know the datepicker would try to find the date in real time! See updated answer.

Comment: I used Three input tag, three input tag has different id and set to different date selected... how to used Tag id pass on .................  $('.datepicker').datepicker().bind('click keyup', function() this function

Answer (score 1):

It will not hide your text box and you can also edit the date.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({          
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "Images/ico_calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    maxDate:"+6M",
    showOtherMonths: true

});
$('.date-picker').next().datepicker().bind('click', function() {
    $('<p>hello world</p>').insertBefore('.ui-datepicker-header');
});
```